# How can I test Xcode Project on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, simulator

I have developed a view based project in Xcode. It is successfully running in iPhone Simulator. But I want to test this project on real iPhone device to check the behavior of application.
Is there any way I can test my application on iPhone device without buying Apple Developer's License? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope... which is a good reason, IMHO, to target Android, instead.

Comment: @Michael, it all comes down to "Do you want to be a big fish in a tiny market, or a little fish in a huge market?"  There are people making millions off iPhone apps.  I bet nobody is making a living off Android apps.

Comment: @PaulTomblin http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/12/10-billion-android-market-downloads-and.html Now that's the tiny market you're talking about?

Comment: @Qlimax So lots of people have downloaded Android.  Does that prove that Android app sales dollars are high?  Not really.  According to this article http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/05/27/distimo_app_store_report/ app sales were still sluggish, over a year after I wrote the comment you're responding to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is not.  You pay the $99, and you get the ability to load software onto (a few, I believe) real iPhone/iPods.  See http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/develop.html#compare for details.

Comment: You can register up to 100 device (iPhone, iTouch, iPad) UDIDs with your account. You can put dev builds directly on them via sync cable or do an adHoc release which you can send the app to the users and they install using their iTunes. The app will only run on devices with registered UDIDs.

Answer (score 1):

No, Dear you can't install any app onto the iphone without their(Apple) permission. YOu have to buy the Apple's Developer License. That's the bad news for you..

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can borrow devices to test your app project developed using Xcode, it is also easy and simple you can also link as many devices to test your app. I did this for one of my game app.

check the link below for reliable discussion

[Install iPhone application in my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293185/install-iphone-application-in-my-device/19342048#19342048)

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/648853-do-i-have-to-have-an-iphone-in-order-to-create-and-test-an-application/