# Install iPhone application in my device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was recently developing an iPhone application using Xcode. Now I want to install this app on my iPhone in order to test it.How can I do this? could you tell me  please a step by step answer because I am new to this.

I have already created an account on the 
[iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/)
now what is the next step?

As per Apple guidelines:

> To test your app on a variety of devices and iOS versions, create a special distribution provisioning profile, called an ad hoc provisioning profile, and send it, along with the app, to testers. An ad hoc provisioning profile doesn’t require that testers be enrolled in an Apple Developer Program, be added to your team, create signing certificates, or use Xcode to run your app. Instead, app testers simply install the app and the ad hoc provisioning profile on their device to launch the app. You can then collect and analyse crash reports or logs from these testers to resolve problems before you ship your app.

Can I do what is mentioned here? and if yes how ?

Comment: Do you have a paid iOS developers account? Because without a paid account you will not be able to do this.

Comment: no it is free ,, so what is : ad hoc provisioning profile

Comment: With the free account you **can not** test/run apps on a device.

Comment: Have anyone tried to do this on a jailbroken iOS device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> go to memeber login area and login with your credential..

[image]

> go to certificate , Identifiers & Profile tab

[image]

> go to keychain access and create a .csr file and save it, it'll
>   required for creating certificates

[image]

> 1. create a certificate from certificate tab
> 2. create App Ids from identifier tab
> 3. Register your device UDID from Devices tab
> 4. Create distribution profile from Provisioning Profile tab and download & save it.
> 5. Install the Provisioning profile to your device and build your project using that profile.

[image]

> Archive your project and create .ipa file

[image]

> Final step: Install that .ipa file to your device.

Hope it'll help you. Happy Coding.....

Comment: i do not have: certificate , Identifiers & Profile tab !!

Comment: It is highly required!

Comment: why i do not have it ? i will add a screenshot to what i get when log in to member center

Comment: Your account must be a paid account. I guess it's free account that's why you are not able to see that tabs

Comment: yes it is free.. do you mean that i can not download my app on my personal iphone unless i pay 99$/year

Comment: That profile is use to distribute your app for some register UDID devices.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38963/discussion-between-tapas-pal-and-ahmad-d)

Answer (score 4):

With the free account you **`can not`** test/run apps on a device.