# how to run xcode 5 project on iphone 5 with ios 7.0.2

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

Can any one tell me how can I rum my xcode project on real iphone 5 with ios 7 installed without developers account

Comment: Sure. Jailbreak the phone, install AppSync (or whatever it is called nowadays), and patch Xcode in order it not to require the developer cert for code signing.

Comment: To do so you nee to create provisioning profile.  Follow the [link to create provisioning profile][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293185/install-iphone-application-in-my-device/19293531#19293531

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way of doing what you want to do without an Apple Developer Account and a registration of the iOS Developer Program.

1. Make an Apple Developer Account.
2. Sign up for iOS Developer Programme.
3. Create a Provisioning Profile for your device.
4. Run your
   app on the device.

That is if you are attempting to run your app in a regular device.

I believe there are ways to achieve this if your device is jailbroken, however I advise you to refrain from doing so.